# Angular2 - submitting a form from typescript

Tags: angular, angular2-forms

I have a html form on a pop up

```
<iframe name="iframeadd" id="iframeadd" src="" class="iframe_hide"></iframe>

<form class="xxform" target="iframeadd"  method="post"  #xxinfoForm (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
```

I would like to submit the form on `button` click from a typescript method instead of directly submitting the `HTML`. Also I would like to post the request via the `iframe`. After getting success response I want to close the pop up and do further processing?

Is there a way to do this in `Angular 2` instead of using `JQuery`?